# what is the use back ticks in scala

Tags: scala

I found following code in a book

```
val list = List(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
val result = (0 /: list) { (`running total`, `next element`) ⇒
  `running total` - `next element`
}
```

Are backticks used to create a variable name with spaces?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using back tickets invalid variable name can be valid. You can use scala reserved key words as variable names as well when you use backticks. You can use space separated and even newline separated variables with back ticks as valid variable names.

#### Scala backticks

```
scala> val `hello world` = "asdjaklsdja"
hello world: String = asdjaklsdja

scala> val `val` = "fasfasadsas"
val: String = fasfasadsas

scala> val `class` = "fasfasadsas"
class: String = fasfasadsas

scala> val `case` = "fasfasadsas"
case: String = fasfasadsas

scala> val `foo bar \n foo bar` = "asdasdasd"
foo bar
 foo bar: String = asdasdasd
```

#### Backticks in Pattern matching

```
scala> val age = 18
age: Int = 18

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def is18(a: Int): Boolean = a match {
 case `age` => true
 case _ => false
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

is18: (a: Int)Boolean

scala> is18(21)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> is18(18)
res1: Boolean = true
```

In pattern matching, it helps you to use variable as if its a concreate value.