# scala Does match end in Nil?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

I'm new in Scala and I'm reading [fp in Scala](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala). There is an example code in this book and I type this into Idea:

```
sealed trait mList[+A]
case object mNil extends mList[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A] (head:A, tail:mList[A]) extends mList[A]

object mList {
  def sum(ints: mList[Int] ): Int = ints match {
    case mNil => 0
    case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
  }

  def apply[A](as: A*): mList[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) mNil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail:_*))
}
```

Then I get a warning from Idea that `case Cons(h, t)` is unreachable.

I'm sure in this book `case Nil` comes before `case Cons`. But when I run the code this way I always get sum=0.

So should I swap the orders of the two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could swap the cases but actually this is not necessary.

You are missing backticks if you'd like to refer to the object (or another existing variable)

```
def sum(ints: mList[Int]): Int = ints match {
  case `mNil` => 0
  case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
}
```

Otherwise without backticks `mNil` (lower-case) is a new-variable pattern like in `case x => ...` i.e. it matches everything.

Alternatively you could call the object in upper case. Then you don't need backticks

```
case object MNil extends mList[Nothing]

def sum(ints: mList[Int]): Int = ints match {
  case MNil => 0
  case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
}
```

[what is the use back ticks in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846336/what-is-the-use-back-ticks-in-scala)

[Need clarification on Scala literal identifiers (backticks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks)

[Why does pattern matching in Scala not work with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078022/why-does-pattern-matching-in-scala-not-work-with-variables)

[Pattern matching on non-literal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344564/pattern-matching-on-non-literal-values)