# Unreachable case except for null in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unreachable-code, non-exhaustive-patterns

I have the following helper function. I am trying to create a word frequency `List`. `(a,b,a) => [(a,2),(b,1)]`:

```
def add_to_lop(c:Char, lop: List[(Char, Int)]):List[(Char, Int)] = {
      lop match {
        case List() => List((c,1))
        case (c, _)::xs => add_to_pair(c,lop.head)::lop.tail
        case _ => lop.head::add_to_lop(c, lop.tail)
      }
```

I think so long as the head of `lop` does not satisfy `lop.head._1==c`, the case should reach the third one (barring lop being empty where it is the first case). However compilation warns that the third case is almost unreachabe - `case _ => lop.head::add_to_lop(c, lop.tail); Unreachable case except for null (if this is intentional, consider writing case null => instead).`. Can you help me identify my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

```
case (`c`, _)::xs =>
```

with backticks instead of

```
case (c, _)::xs =>
```

In the pattern, `c` without backtics is a new variable, so matches everything, not only the previous `c`.

[scala Does match end in Nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75281503/scala-does-match-end-in-nil)

Comment: OP should have got a warning about this like "shadowing variable", isn't it? I'm pretty sure I had such warnings but I don't remember with which compilation flag.

Comment: @GaëlJ Not sure https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/options-lookup.html